# Inuitive analogy for localization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, anderson-localization

I'm looking for a plain English analogy for electron/wave localization. And in particular [weak localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_localization) and [Anderson/strong localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_localization). Is it possible to describe these phenomena in simple terms as I haven't been able to find anything intuitive on the net.